# Javascript Eval() thinks first value is a function

Tags: javascript, html, regex, angular, eval

I am writing a function that will evaluate expressions in an input field and return the sum.

Currently is working but I am running into an error that I just cannot figure out. [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/GKJasJLY884sZ6IeMmPp?p=preview) is my code in Plunker.

```
function linkFunction(scope) {
    var PO = 10;
    scope.value = PO;
    scope.result = '';

    scope.Evaluate = function (input) { 
        if (input.match(/[a-zA-Z]/g) != null) { //to check if user has inputted a letter between a-z, case sensitive.
            return alert("You must only use numbers, not letters")
        } else if (input.match(/[!"^£$&[{}\]?\\@#~<>_'|`¬:;,=]/g) != null) { //to check if user has inputted a special symbol 
            return alert("You must only use the symbols specified")
        } else if (input.match(/\.\d*\.+/g) != null) { //to check if user has inputted a doubled decimal eg 10.2.2
            return alert("You can only use 1 decimal point")
        } else if (input.match(/\.{2,}/g) != null) {//to check if user has inputted a two decimals eg 10..1
            return alert("You cannot put two decimals one after another")
        }

        // if (input.match(/\d*\(\d\W\d\)/g) != null){

        // }

        var percentPattern = /[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+%/g; 
        var expressionResults = input.match(percentPattern);
        if (scope.enablePercentage) { //if parameter = 1, then do this code.
            if (expressionResults != null) { //if user has entered into the input field
                if (expressionResults.length > 1) { //if you user has finished the RegEx (%, is the end of the RegEx, so code will think its the end of the array, therefore you cannot add another %)
                    return alert("Too many % values");
                } else {// user has met all requirements
                    var percentageValue = parseFloat(expressionResults) * PO / 100;
                    input = input.replace(expressionResults, percentageValue);
                }
            }
        } else if (expressionResults != null) { //if parameter = 0, then do this code. Parameter is off, but user has entered percentage
            return alert("You cannot use %");
        }

        scope.result = eval(input);
    }

}});
```

If you write 10(5+3) it gives you an error

> TypeError: 10 is not a function

Obviously if a user ran this code they would expect to see the value 80.
Eval thinks that 10() is a function.
Does anyone know how to fix this problem. Thanks

Comment: `10(5+3)` is not a valid mathematical expression as per javascript. It should be `10*(5+3)`.

Comment: You're thinking literal mathematics, as you'd write it yourself. Computers, unless you write the logic to tell it what to do, are pretty dumb. You would need to write `10 * (5 + 3)` for JavaScript to understand and give you the result `80`

Comment: That code is actually from hell. Should be a lot easier and more readable to be done...

Comment: Are you doing this for the fun of it, or for learning? If you are planning to use in production, you may want to try out http://mathjs.org/

Comment: Thank you for the range of replies. I will be using this for production. mathjs.org will solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

`eval` expects you to pass it JavaScript, not algebra.

If you want to multiply two values together then you must use a [Multiplicative Operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-multiplicative-operators).

```
10 * (5+3)
```